# Anomalous dimension for 1D quantum Ising model

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, phase-transition, ising-model, scaling

I am reading Chapter 10.2, *Quantum Phase Transition--Subir Sachdev*(P144), it said

> All previous scaling dimensions of the d = 1 Ising model coincided with their so-called engineering dimension; the anomalous dimension is deﬁned by the difference of the scaling and engineering dimensions, and so all previous anomalous dimensions were $0$.

However, we know for 1D quantum Ising model, the scaling dimension of $\sigma_z$ is $1/8$, which is different from its zero engineering  dimension. For this question, this book gives the explanation:

> This can happen without violating equality of engineering dimensions (which must always be preserved) because we have the additional freedom to use powers of the lattice energy scale $J$ (or the lattice spacing, $a$) in deﬁning the continuum limit of observables. Indeed, only the combination $J^{ 1/8} σ^z$ has correlators that are ﬁnite in the continuum limit $a → 0$.

What  confuses me is that the multiplier $J$ or $a$ also has non-zero scaling dimension and engineering dimension so that it seems impossible to obtain an equation. Also, whatever other trick, in fact, the scaling and engineering dimensions of $\sigma^z$ are different, how can we still say anomalous dimension is zero?

Answer (score 1):

In the scaling/continuum limit, the microscopic constants should really be taken to $J \rightarrow \infty$, $a \rightarrow 0$, and $g \rightarrow 1$, so one shouldn't refer to the "scaling dimensions" of $a$ and $J$. Once one puts the theory into its scaling form (Eq. (10.25) in Sachdev, which crucially *must* be independent of the microscopic constants), the scaling and engineering dimensions of all constants/fields will no longer need to coincide, and the way this works out is precisely that these microscopic constants are really lurking in the definition of the full theory.